# End2End encryption IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence

Tags: javascript, java, webcrypto-api, webcrypto, end-to-end-encryption

I'm generating the Public and Private key by using the Native Browser crypto API as below:

```js
export const generateKeyPair = async (): Promise<CryptoKeyPair> => {
    return await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDH",
            namedCurve: "P-384",
        },
        true,
        ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"],
    );
};
```

Then I'll export the `publicKey` by using the `exportKey` function under the `window.crypto.subtle` as below:

```js
const keyPair: CryptoKeyPair = yield generateKeyPair();
const publicKeyArrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer = yield window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", keyPair.publicKey);
const publicKeyAsBase64 = arrayBufferToBase64(publicKeyArrayBuffer);
```

If you have any suggestions, please let me know and help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Maybe the Java code expects the key in a different format. Post the Java code and also an example of a key exported with the JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, This is an example of the javascript code result: BNCGjPDvjrzqqVSAru54rWN0OVYfq/98EC6O+UH/mId965tsdZbccQDXIKvUBAxq5Q7DhTnp4nDfNp9lSbo99i8MXdbaPV3iA7bB39+zhzUWEEnkfQdzrAF3cWUq7RWRRw==

Comment: Unfortunately I've no access to the Backend's code

Comment: The key is an uncompressed EC key: 0x04|<x>|<y>. Keys can be specified in different formats. You have to find out the required format of the Java code somehow. Of course you can also try common formats, e.g. X.509/SPKI.

Comment: I updated the question, Please check it out.

Comment: The public key should be in ASN1 format which is finally converted to Base64 for sending to the Server and receive the Server publicKey.

Comment: `X509EncodedKeySpec()` corresponds to the X.509/SPKI format, DER encoded. `exportKey()` supports the spki format (s. e.g. [here](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#ecdh---exportkey)).

Comment: This is an Example of valid publicKey and if I send it to the Backend, it will response me a publicKey
`MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEmDOvSajZFQT261yTdkE0EloJ8AP4gJKO7kDLNnNlT9fLHuWhl+shys58xCdT4ABtPZOSNtyTRQNh1rDvIkp3EA==`.
And I also tried using the `spki` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236652/discussion-between-ali-torki-and-topaco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both codes use different curves, the Java code secp256r1 (aka P-256), the JavaScript code P-384. To make both codes compatible, the JavaScript code must apply the same curve as the Java code, i.e. P-256 (s. also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EcKeyGenParams#properties)).

The Java code exports a public EC key in X.509/SPKI format, which is Base64 encoded. The JavaScript code exports the public key in uncompressed format `0x04|<x>|<y>`. The export in X.509/SPKI format is possible with `spki` as 1st parameter, s. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/exportKey#parameters) and [here](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#ecdh---exportkey).

Comment: Do you know how can I encrypt a string with the `serverPublicKey`(which is a base64 string) and my `privateKey` by AES-256? and also the decryption process? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This cannot be answered in the context of a comment. Please post a new question on SO with all the necessary information. If needed, you can reference this post.